# DateTime conversion for HubSpot API is not working

Tags: c#, datetime

I am pushing date/time values into the HubSpot CRM system via their API. For date/time values, the HS API requires UNIX format, which is milliseconds from Epoch (1/1/1970 12:00 AM). [[HubSpot docs: https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/faq/how-should-timestamps-be-formatted-for-hubspots-apis]](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/faq/how-should-timestamps-be-formatted-for-hubspots-apis)

But my dates are representing incorrectly. I am pulling dates from a SQL database that is in EST, and performing the following conversion:

```
string dbValue = "2019-02-03 00:00:00";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dbValue);
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
long apiValue = Convert.ToInt64(dt.Subtract(epoch).TotalMilliseconds);
```

However, in HubSpot, the date field shows `2/2/2019`. The time zone in HubSpot is set to UTC -4 Eastern Time.

It seems like there is some conversion issue, but I do not know what to do to correct it. I've tried using `DateTime.SpecifiyKind` to explicitly set `dt` to local before converting to long:

```
dt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dt, System.DateTimeKind.Local);
```

But that hasn't worked either. I tried doing a basic test:

```
var dt1 = new DateTime(2019, 4, 1, 12, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
var dt2 = new DateTime(2019, 4, 1, 12, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
Console.WriteLine(dt1.Subtract(dt2).TotalSeconds);
```

But the result was `0`. I am in CST, and I was expecting like a 5 hour difference. I feel like I am missing some fundamental concept here on how DateTimes work in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- Subtracting `DateTime` values does not take `DateTimeKind` into account.
- .NET Framework 4.6 and higher have conversion functions to/from Unix time built in to the `DateTimeOffset` class, so you don't need to do any subtraction at all.
- When you say `EST` or `CST`, I'll assume you meant US Eastern Time or US Central Time.  Keep in mind that because of daylight saving time, that `EDT` or `CDT` might apply to some of your values.
- You shouldn't be parsing from strings if the value is coming from your database.  I'll assume you just gave that for the example here.  But in your actual code, you should be doing something like:

  ```
  DateTime dt = (DateTime) dataReader("field");
  ```

  (If you're using Entity Framework or some other ORM, then this part would be handled for you.)
- It doesn't matter what time zone the SQL Server is *located* in.  It matters rather what time zone the `dbValue` you have is intended to represent.  A best practice is to keep time in terms of UTC, in which case the server's time zone should be irrelevant.
- If the datetime stored in your SQL server is actually in UTC, then you can simply do this:

  ```
  long apiValue = new DateTimeOffset(dt, TimeSpan.Zero).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
  ```
- If the datetime stored in your SQL server really is in US Eastern Time, then you will need to first convert from Eastern Time to UTC:

  ```
  TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
  DateTime utc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt, tz);
  long apiValue = new DateTimeOffset(utc).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
  ```

  - Note that the Windows time zone ID of `"Eastern Standard Time"` represents US Eastern Time including EDT when applicable, despite having the word "Standard" in the middle.
  - If you are running in .NET Core on a non-Windows platform, pass `"America/New_York"` instead.  (And if you need to write for cross-platform resiliency, use my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library.)
- Lastly, though it might be a bit dangerous to assume the time in the DB is in the same local time as the code accessing the DB, if you really wanted to make such a gamble, you could do it like this:

  ```
  long apiValue = new DateTimeOffset(dt).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
  ```

  That works only if `dt.Kind` is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` or `DateTimeKind.Local`, as it would then apply the local time zone.  But again, I would recommend against this.

Comment: It looks like I will need to "manually" convert to eastern time zone. For more background: By the time my code is hit, the database data has passed through another system and I'm getting it as a text node in an XML document. So, text parsing. Yea. And, the source database is storing the dates in Eastern time zone, not UTC, unfortunately. In this case, your last scenario is fairly low risk. The webserver and database server are hosted by the same company, and are both in Eastern time. But, I see your point.

Comment: Yep, then I'd recommend the middle option using `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc` with a specific time zone.  That way you're in control.  (Also, you might consider using `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact` instead of `Convert.ToDateTime`, as again you'll have much more control.)

Comment: That worked. I had a chance to test out the changes. This project is .NET 4.5, so I don't have access to the `ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()` method. But using my `Convert.ToInt64(dt.Subtract(epoch).TotalMilliseconds)` worked just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, subtracting is fine if both values are in UTC.  Just don't try to do that with local time unless you convert to UTC first. ;)